# jQuery check lazyload plugin initilize for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I work with jQuery lazyload image plugin www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload.

HTML:

```
 <img class="img-thumbnail mag-thumbnail img-responsive lazy" width="129" height="177" data-original="http://localhost/cms/cache/images/129x177-1231234.png" src="http://localhost/cms/cache/images/129x177-1231234.png" >
 <img class="img-thumbnail mag-thumbnail img-responsive lazy" width="129" height="177" data-original="http://localhost/cms/cache/images/129x177-123.png" src="http://localhost/cms/cache/images/129x177-123.png" >
 <img class="img-thumbnail mag-thumbnail img-responsive lazy" width="129" height="177" data-original="http://localhost/cms/cache/images/129x177-1234.png" src="http://localhost/cms/cache/images/129x177-1234.png" >
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

how do can i make sure lazyload worked for my image?!

Answer (score 3):

In Browser developer console type:

```
 typeof($("img").lazyload) === "function"
```

if you see `true` lazyload plugin enabled in your page.